# Spring: Make a bean/service only available to some specific classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a service called "AccessService" but I want to make sure it is only available to some specific classes (in a specific Java package). So, if any other class wants to auto-wire that service, the operation should fail.

Does Spring provide this feature?

Comment: You could make the class private, then the class is private to the package and no other packages have direct access to it. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be a [request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) *[based scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_REQUEST)* which would to some degree limit a bean to the life cycle of a servlet.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html